# Javascript doesnt work in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working javascript in JS fiddle but when copied to html file it doesn't fully work. I have checked other post related to the same topic but no solution.
the filter is not working

https://jsfiddle.net/jpm50m0s/

Code in HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            table.innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                var js = "apple";
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                var td = document.createElement("td");

                td.innerHTML = js + i ;
                tr.appendChild(td);
                table.appendChild(tr);
            }});

            $(function() {
                var $rows = $('tr');
                $('#search').keyup(function() {
                    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                    $rows.show().filter(function() {
                        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                        return !~text.indexOf(val);
                    }).hide();
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="data-heading right">
        Search:<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
    </span>
    <table id="table"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error in your console?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: The code you have pasted here is different from the code in your fiddle - which is closer to your *real* code?

Comment: the code in the HTML is the one I used, its the same in the fiddle

Comment: no, the code here has an `onload = function x()` which your fiddle does *not* have.

Comment: This is the solution I got from a similar post to load the first function to display the for loop, If i remove this, the for loop is not loaded anymore

Comment: @Jamiec is correct. This fiddle matches what you have in the question, although it still works without errors: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jpm50m0s/2/

Comment: Just put the `for` loop inside your ready function. There is no need for `onload = function x()` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$(document).ready(function()` instead of onload

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = document.getElementById("table");

table.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var js = "apple";
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");

  td.innerHTML = js + i ;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}


var $rows = $('tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear `$(function(){...})` and `$(document).ready(function(){...})` are the same thing. What this answer points out is that you have a function `onload` as well in your code which is never called.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer even on your jsfiddle, exept on the first load, you never pass through loop

Answer (score 0):

You have got confused between how to trigger an action using jQuery when the page loads.

This part executes when the DOM is loaded

```
$(function() {
  ... everything here runs when the page is loaded
});
```

There is another way of writing the same thing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  .... totally same as above code.
});
```

So, in your case you can just get rid of the `onload = function x()` part and put it all inside your existing "onload" function (there is no need for a second one!)

```
$(function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var js = "apple";
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");

        td.innerHTML = js + i ;
        tr.appendChild(td);
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }


    var $rows = $('tr');
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: i think i really got confused, I thought the table must be loaded first before a search can be executed.

Answer (score -1):

Dont put your code in the `<head>` part. Move it to the bottom of your `<body>` tag:

```
Search:
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id='here_table'></table>
<script>
var table = document.getElementById("here_table");
table.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var js = "apple";
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");

  td.innerHTML = js + i ;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
function myFunction(index) {
  var cells = this.textContent;
  alert("Value of row " + cells + ' Index:' + index);
}

$(function() {
var $rows = $('tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2vtppaov/

Comment: If you're going to do this, there's no point having the `$(function(){..})` part!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of keyup event try keppress event.
It worked for me.